# Project Euler Q1 Ruby

Tags: ruby

With my code, I get the correct sum for numbers below 10, however when I do numbers below 1000, it appears to not be correct. I don't understand why simply changing the 10 to 1000 is causing me to not get the correct solution. I am getting 266333.

```
def multiplesofthreeandfive(number1, number2)
total1 = 0
total2 = 0

for i in 1..999

    if i % number1 == 0
        #puts "#{i}"
        total1 = total1 + i
    else
        #nothing
    end
end
for i in 1..999
#puts "#{i}"
    if i % number2 == 0
        #puts "#{i}"
        total2 = total2 + i
    else
        #nothing
    end
end
total3 = total1 + total2
puts "The 3 total is #{total1}"
puts "The 5 total is #{total2}"
puts "added together #{total3}"
end

puts multiplesofthreeandfive(3, 5)
```

Comment: You’re counting multiples of 15 twice. 15 > 10.

Comment: I see. From the question, I was not under the impression that I couldn't add a number twice. edit - I read the question with you solution in mind, and it makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: You should begin be stating the problem that you are attempting to solve with your code. The reader should not have to read the code to figure out the problem it addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider how you can improve your answer.

I infer you are computing the sum of all integers between `1` and `999` that are divisible by `number1` or `number2`.

Some points to consider:

- You are not using `total2`, so do not define it.
- Do not use `for`. It's always better to use one of Ruby's iterators, such as `each`, `map`, `select` and so on. One reason for this is that the elements in the `for` loop are not encapsulated within the loop, whereas they are in an enumerator's block. Many Rubiests never use `for`.
- Do not hardwire values that could be parameters, here `1` and `999`. This makes the method more robust and no more complex.
- Do not `puts` the result within the method. You may want to use the method elsewhere to simply obtain the sum.
- Your method name includes `three` and `five`, but those are not necessarily the values of the two arguments.
- Use underscores in names of variables and methods to improve readability.
- Method names should begin with a verb and be descriptive, but avoid making them overly-long.
- Rather than `if <condition> <operation> else end`, use `<operation> if <condition>` or `<operation> unless <condition>`.
- Use Ruby's powerful enumerators, especially ones in the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html) module. When you want to "sum", think [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`).
- Do not define temporary variables when they are not needed for calculations or clarity, to avoid one potential source of errors.

You might write:

```
def sum_multiples_of_n1_or_n2(n1, n2, from, to)
  (from..to).reduce(0) { |tot,i| tot + ((i%n1==0 || i%n2==0) ? i : 0) }
end

sum_multiples_of_n1_or_n2(3, 5, 1, 999)
  #=> 233168 

puts "The total for %d to %d, when n1 = %d and n2 = %d, is %d." %
  [1, 999, 3, 5, sum_multiples_of_n1_or_n2(3, 5, 1, 999)]
The total for 1 to 999, when n1 = 3 and n2 = 5, is 233168.
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved thanks to minitech. I was not thinking about the question properly. I changed my code, and it worked!

```
def multiplesofthreeandfive(number1, number2)
total1 = 0
total2 = 0

for i in 1..999

    if i % number1 == 0 || i % number2 == 0
        #puts "#{i}"
        total1 = total1 + i
    else
        #nothing
    end
end
total3 = total1 + total2
puts "The 3 total is #{total1}"
end

puts multiplesofthreeandfive(3, 5)
```